# Reactive hibernate on Quarkus with Flyway

Tags: java, hibernate, flyway, quarkus, hibernate-reactive

I face a problem when trying to use Quarkus Flyway extension with Quarkus Reactive Hibernate & RESTEasy. When starting my application, I get the following error:

```
[io.qu.ru.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Booting an Hibernate Reactive serviceregistry on a non-reactive RecordedState!
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.boot.registry.PreconfiguredReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder.checkIsReactive(PreconfiguredReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder.java:76)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.boot.registry.PreconfiguredReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(PreconfiguredReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder.java:66)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.rewireMetadataAndExtractServiceRegistry(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:156)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:82)
```

Here are the relevant Quarkus configurations:

```yaml
quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: "postgresql"
    username: "sarah"
    password: "connor"
    jdbc:
      ~: true
      url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mybase"
    reactive:
      ~: true
      url: "postgresql://localhost:5432/mybase"
```

And the relevant dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Disabling the JDBC configuration with `~: false` avoids the exception but then the application does not launch the Flyway migration at start time. In that case, I see the following message:

```
[io.qu.ag.de.AgroalProcessor] (build-39) The Agroal dependency is present but no JDBC datasources have been defined.
```

I found on some Quarkus issues that it's indeed not possible to run a reactive and a blocking database connection at the same time but is there a way to make Flyway working with a **reactive** Quarkus application ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently they indeed don't seem support both blocking JDBC and a reactive sql client at the same time.
A workaround is to disable JDBC for the Quarkus runtime and write your own wrapper to execute the Flyway migration.

Below workaround is based on their corresponding [GitHub issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/10716).

Flyway wrapper to run when application starts:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class RunFlyway {

    @ConfigProperty(name = "myapp.flyway.migrate")
    boolean runMigration;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.reactive.url")
    String datasourceUrl;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.username")
    String datasourceUsername;
    @ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.password")
    String datasourcePassword;

    public void runFlywayMigration(@Observes StartupEvent event) {
        if (runMigration) {
            Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource("jdbc:" + datasourceUrl, datasourceUsername, datasourcePassword).load();
            flyway.migrate();
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```xml
<!-- DB -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-reactive-pg-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!-- Flyway -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-flyway</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-postgresql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.yml:

```yaml
myapp:
  flyway:
    migrate: true
quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: postgresql
    username: myuser
    password: mypassword
    jdbc: false
    reactive:
      url: postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, it's indeed now working (until there's a more official solution). An important point: if we use an **empty password** during development, you have to change the property with `@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.datasource.password", defaultValue = "") Optional<String> datasourcePassword;` to make it working